# Enable content plugins in custom component (Joomla 3)

Tags: components, joomla3.0

I have build several custom Joomla components and they all work pretty nice. Now I want to add social sharing buttons to my frontend view and I want to use an existing plugin to generate them. Does anybody know how to accomplish this. How can you enable contentplugins in your own component. (The plugin I want to use is ITP-SocialButtons.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable [content prepare](http://docs.joomla.org/Triggering_content_plugins_in_your_extension) and import your plugin:

```
  $plugin = "{pluginname parameter}";
  echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', $plugin);
```

You could also use [JpluginHelper](http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JPluginHelper.html) class:

```
  $plugin = JPluginHelper::getPlugin($type, $name);
  echo $plugin->variable;
```

Good Luck!